# difference between RestangularProvider and RestangularConfigurer

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I wanted to add an interceptor to my module.

Here is the intial state:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,RestangularProvider)  {

   RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/app/services');

});
```

I modified with this:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider, RestangularConfigurer)     {

  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/app/services');

  RestangularConfigurer.addFullRequestInterceptor(function (element, operation, route, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {

    if (operation === 'get'){
        console.log("RestangularProvider: call to get");
        params.ts= new Date();
    }

    return {
        element: element,
        headers: headers,
        params: params,
        httpConfig: httpConfig
    };

  });
});
```

However, I add an error:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: RestangularConfigurer
```

So I replaced RestangularConfigurer by RestangularProvider.

But I do not clearly understand how that works, and what's happening behind the scenes.
Could you explain me that ?

Comment: I think it is simplest to say that RestangularConfigurer is just a renamed RestangularProvider object in a context where you are overriding the global config settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there is no **RestangularConfigurer** module. You have only **Restangular** and its provider **RestangularProvider**.

Let's start with angularjs documentation for [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers).

Please esspecially read **Provider Recipe** as I do not duplicate it again here.

As a summary RestangularProvider is just a recipe how Restangular api should be build as you decide it in config module there is no Restangular api yet, but you have your recipe.

On the other hand Restangular will be bootstraped after your main module bootstraped, so in config there is actually no **Restangular** module yet.

If you still insist using **Restangular** instead its provider you can use it in **module#run** instead of **module#config**.